# Inserting Data with NSFetchedResultController using NSManagedObjectContext subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` in my iOS Application. I need to insert some data. I'm trying to do that with the following code:

```
Shop *shop = (Shop *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shop" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[shop setName:@"test"];
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

Nothing. I don't have any errors, my application doesn't terminate. Maybe I insert data incorrectly.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Hear about the new object in the delegate method?

Comment: How do you know you're not getting any errors? You're passing nil as the error parameter. Is `performFetch`returning `YES`?

Comment: You should add other details...

Comment: Don't cast from `+[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:]`.  That method returns `id`.  You **NEVER** need to cast it. If you are casting in Objective-C you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Show how you're creating the FRC.

Comment: how about passing NSError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your results, pass and check a non-nil error parameter.

```
Shop *shop = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shop"     inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[shop setName:@"test"];
NSLog(@"%@", shop);
NSError *error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"MOC save failed: %@ %@", error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo);
}
NSParameterAssert(self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest);
NSLog(@"fetchRequest: %@", self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest);
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"performFetch failed: %@ %@", error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo);
}
```

Comment: `insetNewObjectForEntityForName:` invokes internally `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` which always returns a value. If you pass an incorrect entity (or a nil entity), it throws an exception.

Comment: "This needs some basic debugging. Check your results ..." is a valuable comment, but not an answer.

Comment: Get rid of that cast Hal :)

Comment: <Shop: 0x16d94420> (entity: Shop; id: 0x16d944f0 <x-coredata:///Shop/t7BA89E9A-6358-45A7-BA9A-906FA473F2F92> ; data: {
    name = test;
    })

Comment: Nikita, if that's the only output you're seeing, then your problem lies elsewhere. What behavior are you expecting? What happens instead? How are you setting up the `NSFetchedResultsController`?